# Проблемма с тригером в mySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, триггер

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите, что не так у меня с тригером.

> CREATE TRIGGER `t_ins_name` BEFORE INSERT ON `ecity`
>    FOR EACH ROW UPDATE `ecity` SET `name`=UPPER(NEW.`name`)

он вызывает ошибку 1442

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь задать триггер, который обновляет всю таблицу, для которой же и назначается. В результате его выполнения создастся бесконечное дерево вызовов (каждый апдейт внутри триггера будет вызывать еще один апдейт всей таблицы, а для каждой затронутой записи нужно будет снова вызывать триггер), что и не дает сделать MySQL.

ЕМНИП триггеры вообще не имеют права работать с таблицей, на которой они установлены.